# Simple method call won't work in java

Tags: java

This is an exercise and I was asked to write the methods `charAt()`,`length()` `startsWith()` and call these methods in the `main` function.

The expected output should be

> abcde
>
> c 5

For some reason that i don't know so it's not printing out those out puts and I was unable to call the `startsWith()` method.

Question (1) I can't call the method `startsWith()`.

Question (2) It compiles when i comment out the `startsWith()` but than

it only print the letter not the index and length.

```
public interface CSequence {
    char charAt(int n);
    int length();
}
class ImmutableCSequence implements CSequence {
    private char[] chars;
    public ImmutableCSequence(char[] chars) {
        this.chars = new char[chars.length];
        for (int pos = 0; pos < chars.length; pos++)
            this.chars[pos] = chars[pos];
    }
    public boolean startsWith(char c) {
        boolean b = false;
        if (this.chars.length > 0 && c == this.chars[0])
            b = true;
        return b;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return new String(this.chars);
    }

    public char charAt(int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
            i=(char) n;
        }
        return (char)n;
    }
    
    public int length() {
        return this.chars.length;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        CSequence cs = new ImmutableCSequence(letters);
        System.out.println(cs);
        char c = cs.charAt(2);
        int len = cs.length();
        System.out.println(c + " " + len);
        //boolean b = cs.startsWith('a');
    }
}
```

Comment: What means ` dose not work as it's supposed`?

Comment: its startsWith so might be misspelled?

Comment: startWith != startsWith

Comment: `"dose not work as it's supposed to"` - What is it *supposed to* do?  What *does* it do?  Explain the problem, nobody here can read your mind.

Comment: Why the Loop in `charAt()`?  public char charAt(int n) { return chars[n]}`

Comment: you are doing something weird, create an interface and mix String utils methods like charAt and startWith, weirdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference `cs` is of type `CSequence` and it can only
activate the methods in the interface `CSequence` (the methods charAt and length).
It cannot activate the method `startsWith`.

The method `startWith` can be activated with a reference of typ `ImmutableCSequence`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    CSequence cs = new ImmutableCSequence(letters);
    ImmutableCSequence ck = new ImmutableCSequence(letters);
    System.out.println(cs);
    char c = cs.charAt(2);
    int len = cs.length();
    System.out.println(c + " " + len);
    boolean b = ck.startsWith('a');
```

You can simplify your `charAt()` like this

```
public char charAt(int n){
return this.chars[n];

}
```